# Cannot run OrientDB 3.0 as a windows service

Tags: windows, service, orientdb

I have installed OrientDB and try to run is as a Windows service.

- OrientDB version: Community Edition 3.0.2
- Java version: 1.8.171 SE

OrientDB works for me when run directly from console:
        C:\OrientDB\bin\server.bat

To run OrientDB as a windows service I follow the official guide:
https://orientdb.com/docs/last/admin/Windows-Service.html

```
PS C:\OrientDB\service> .\installService.bat "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll" C:\OrientDB
```

This line is able to create a Windows service, but the service cannot be started.

The event viewer entry says:
    **The OrientDB GraphEd X.X.X service terminated with the following service-specific error: Incorrect function.**

How can I get a running service?
Is the official guide buggy?
Is there any alternative wrapper and a how-to for orientdb there?

Comment: Is your java home correctly set?

Comment: Hi, if you type `echo %JAVA_HOME%`, what kind of output do you get? Thx

Comment: @dgiannotti JAVA_HOME points to "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171"

Comment: Hi loshurik, have you this problem only with OrientDB version: Community Edition 3.0.2 ?

Comment: hi @ldacrema 
I've tried Community Edition 3.0.2 only, so not sure, whether it's version specific